# Caller/Backtrace beyond a thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, backtrace

As far as I know, it is possible to get only the portion of the caller/backtrace information that is within the current thread; anything prior to that (in the thread that created the current thread) is cut off. The following exemplifies this; the fact that `a` called `b`, which called `c`, which created the thread that called `d`, is cut off:

```
def a; b end
def b; c end
def c; Thread.new{d}.join end
def d; e end
def e; puts caller end

a
# => this_file:4:in `d'
#    this_file:3:in `block in c'
```

1. What is the reason for this feature?
2. Is there a way to get the caller/backtrace information beyond the current thread?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both your questions is really the same. Consider a slightly more involved main thread. Instead of simply waiting for the spawned thread to end in `c` the main thread goes on calling other functions, perhaps even returning from `c` and going about it's business while the spawned thread goes on about it's business.

This means that the stack in the main thread has changed since the thread starting in `d` was spawned. In other words, by the time you call `puts caller` the stack in the main thread is no longer in the state it was when the secondary thread was created. There is no way to safely walk back up the stack beyond this point.

So in short:

1. The stack of the spawning thread will not remain in the state it was when the thread was spawned so walking back beyond the start of a threads own stack is not safe.
2. No, since the entire idea behind threads is that they are (pseudo) parallel, their stacks are completely unrelated.

**Update:**

As suggested in the comments, the stack of the current thread can be copied to the new thread at creation time. This would preserve the information that lead up to the thread being created, but the solution is not without its own set of problems.

1. Thread creation will be slower. That could be ok, if there was anything to gain from it, but in this case, is it?
2. What would it mean to return from the thread entry function?

   - It could return to the function that created the thread and keep running as if it was just a function call - only that it now runs in the second thread, not the original one. Would we want that?
   - There could be some magic that ensures that the thread terminates even if it's not at the top of the call stack. This would make the information in the call stack above the thread entry function incorrect anyways.
3. On systems with limits on the stacksize for each thread you could run into problems where the thread ran out of stack even if it's not using very much on it's own.

There probably other scenarios and peculiarities that could be thought out too, but the way threads are created with their own empty stack to start with makes the model both simple and predictable without leaving any useful information out of the callstack.

Comment: Your answer explains why the current implementation cannot return the information. But I don't see it impossible in principle. If each thread copies, at the moment of its creation, the caller information up to the point it was created, and keep it within itself, wouldn't it be possible to get the entire information from within that thread? Am I wrong? I feel that I can even implement that in Ruby level.

Comment: Nothing is impossible, but is there anything to gain? Se updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with my answer.

Things that can be done to a thread from outside of a thread is not only creating it. Other than creating, you can make wake up, etc. So it is not clear what operation should be attributed as part of the caller. For example, suppose there is a thread:

```
1: t = Thread.new{
2:   Thread.stop
3:   puts caller
4: }
5: t.wakeup
```

The thread `t` is created at line 1, but it goes into sleep by itself in line 2, then it wakes up by line 5. So, when we locate ourselves at line 3 `caller`, and consider the caller part outside of the thread, it is not clear whether `Thread.new` in line 1 should be part of it, or `t.wakeup` in line 5 should be part of it. Therefore, there is no clear notion callers beyond the current thread.

However, if we define a clear notion, then it is possible for caller beyond a thread to make sense. For example, always adding the callers up to the creation of the thread may make sense. Otherwise, adding the callers leading to the the most recent `wakeup` or creation may make sense. It is up to the definition.